# How to install roadkill .net wiki in mvc application on development machine and how to use parent authentication(identity server) for roadkill

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-mvc-5, roadkill-wiki

I have my web application uses MVC 5 and identity server3 authentication.I want to use roadkill .net wiki application which uses parent project authentication.Could anyone explain to me what are the steps for it from scratch?
I have added roadkill NuGet package in my project but it is given an error.so how to install it my MVC project and how to add parent project authentication in roadkill.
I am using vs2015 community edition.

Answer (score 0):

Roadkill doesn't currently support OAuth2 without some customisation via the source, but wouldn't be too difficult to add if you are familiar with ASP.NET MVC 4/5.

Version 3 will change all of this and will support OAuth out of the box (it's almost a complete rewrite).